# Compare 2 elements in jQuery (by content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison

So, I have a page with messages. I'm using `jQuery.load` (requesting the exact same page) to refresh the page smoothly once every X seconds.

The problem is that if there are images on the page, they get reloaded.

So basically what I want to do, is to still use the `load` method, but to only update the changed elements.

Is it possible to compare `jQuery('.message-wrapper').first()` with `jQuery('.message-wrapper').last()` and if they have the exact same structure / content, it should return true. Right now if you compare 2 HTML nodes (so JS, not jQuery), you get true only if they are one and the same element.

What I want to do is check the content to see if it's different.

*Disclaimer: I've seen a few similar questions, but none have a working solution.*

Comment: `$('.message-wrapper').first().text() == $('.message-wrapper').last().text()`

Comment: @adeneo if the have the exact same `structure` / content, it should return true

Comment: @adeneo if you'd be so kind to post that as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it. Now I'm ashamed I even asked this question. `.text()`... wow.

Comment: @sabithpocker yes, I requested that, and adeneo's solution wouldn't cover it, but I can deal with that separately, as most of my cases have the same structure, it's just a few exceptions that don't.

Comment: You can use `.html()` instead of `.text()` to account for both structure and content.

Comment: @EduardLuca - added it as an answer !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare the text content of your elements you can use `text()`, or to compare the markup, use `html()` :

```
$('.message-wrapper').first().text() == $('.message-wrapper').last().text()
```

To remove spaces before and after the string, which can be an issue sometimes, you can wrap it in jQuery's `$.trim` method :

```
$.( $('.message-wrapper').first().html() ) === $.( $('.message-wrapper').last().html() )
```